# Get the Bytes out of an IBUFFER

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Im trying to implement a program which utilizes RSA encryption.  I am able to generate the keys but I am only able to store them in an IBUFFER is there any way to get the bytes out of an IBUFFER to store it into a byte array?  I would like to pass the public key to server.

Comment: The trivial google query is "copy ibuffer to array".  All the top hits are good.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same `IBuffer` you get for `WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer` then you can call [`AsStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.windowsruntimebufferextensions.asstream(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a `Stream` pointing at the buffer and use that to operate on the stream. Some samples [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit.UWP/Imaging).
You can also call [`CopyTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598386(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the full buffer in an array if you don't worry about memory usage.